# Updating an array of integer Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uicollectionview

I've an array of mocked data that looks like this:

`var demoInit = [("name", "amount", "place"), ("name", "amount", "place"), ("name", "amount", "place")]`

I am using it in a collection view, and I want my users not to select more than three, I did:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("interestAsset", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! InterestCell
    if selectedItems.count < 3 {
        selectedItems += [indexPath.row]
        selectedCell.holderView.alpha = 0.5
        selectedCell.holderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        selectedCell.checkMark.hidden = false
    }
}
```

If you notice this line `selectedItems += [indexPath.row]` is where I store the selected `indexPath` of the `UICollectionView`. But then the problem I'm having is this, I want to implement deselect, but to implement that, I need to remove that particular stored `indexPath` from the `selectedItems` array. How do I do that? Thanks

Comment: Look at my answer, this should work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete from array using `Array.removeAtIndex`method.

**An example :**

```
var intArray = [1,5,6,8,10]
//Remove 10
intArray.removeAtIndex(intArray.indexOf(10))
print("\(intArray)") // [1,5,6,8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this if it is what you want to achieve:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("interestAsset", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! InterestCell
    if selectedItems.count < 3 {
        selectedItems += [indexPath.row]
        selectedCell.holderView.alpha = 0.5
        selectedCell.holderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        selectedCell.checkMark.hidden = false
    }
    for (var index = 0; index < 3; ++index) {
        if(selectedItems[index] == indexPath.row)
        {
             selectedItems.removeAtIndex(index)
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation:

You are using a for loop in order to loop through your 3 selected Items. If one of them is equal to your indexPath then it is jumping inside of your if-function.
Inside of the if-function it is simply removing the selectedItem form selectedItems.

Write me if it worked...

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to manually keep track of the selected cell in a `UICollectionView`.

Just call `collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()` to retrieve the list of the indexes related to the selected cells.

Your codes becomes like this

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("interestAsset", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! InterestCell
    let selectedItems = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()?.count ?? 0

    if  selectedItems < 3 {
        selectedCell.holderView.alpha = 0.5
        selectedCell.holderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        selectedCell.checkMark.hidden = false
    }
}
```